# How to display saved data in TextEditor when view is reopen

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I am building the app that will store vertical and horizontal measurements at 12 doors.
In there, for each loop creates 12 Sections with vertical and horizontal readings TextEditors for each door. Each text editor stores values to one of the arrays.
When done entering I used **UserDefaults** onDissapear() to store both arrays into a dictionary.
Here's the problem: when I put loadArray(), method that supposed to overwrite vertical and horizontal reading arrays, to onAppear() and revisit the view - none of the stored values are showed( even though, it will print the stored data to console onAppear()).
also, when I revisit the view and then start entering the values then sections with stored data are populated...

**Bound_test.swift.**

```
import SwiftUI

struct Bound_test: View {

let station : String = "Tuscany"

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        VStack {
            Section {
                VStack(){
                    
                    List {
                        Group {
                            NavigationLink(destination: Doors_test(direction: "Outbound"), label: {
                                Text("Out Bound")
                                
                            })
                            NavigationLink(destination: Doors_test(direction: "Inbound"), label: {
                                Text("In Bound")
                            })
                        }
                        .padding(.horizontal,1)
                        .padding(.vertical,3)
                        
                        
                    }
                    .pickerStyle(.wheel)
                }
            }
        }
        
        .navigationTitle("Select direction")
       
    .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
    }
}
}

    struct Bound_test_Previews: PreviewProvider {
        static var previews: some View {
            Bound_test()
        }
    }
```

**Doors.swift**

```
import SwiftUI

struct Doors_test: View {
    
    let station : String = "Tuscany"
    let direction : String
    
    @State var vM  = [String](repeating: "", count: 12) //vert reading
    @State var hM = [String](repeating: "", count: 12) //horiz reading
    
    //constructor
    init(direction: String) {
        self.direction = direction
    }
    
    @FocusState private var amountIsFocust: Bool
    
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Form {
            //creates 12 doors automatically
            ForEach(0..<12) { door in
                Section {
                    HStack {
                        Text ("Vert:")
                        
                        //vert reading
                        TextEditor(text: $vM[door])
                            .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
                            .focused($amountIsFocust)
                        
                    }
                    HStack {
                        Text ("Horizontal:")
                        
                        //horiz reading
                        TextEditor(text: $hM[door])
                            .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
                            .focused($amountIsFocust)
                        
                    }
                    
                } header: {
                    Text ("Door # \(door+1)")
                }
                
            }
            
        }
        .onAppear{
            loadArray()
        }
        .navigationTitle("Enter measurements")
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        .toolbar{
            ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .keyboard) {
                
                Spacer() //moves Done button to the right of the screen
                
                Button("Done") {
                    amountIsFocust = false
                    print(amountIsFocust)
                }
            }
        }
        .onDisappear {
            saveArray() //save array on exit
            
        }
        
    }
    
    //yhis method saves all the readings into dict.
    func saveArray() {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(vM, forKey: "vReadings \(direction)\(station)")
        UserDefaults.standard.set(hM, forKey: "hReadings \(direction)\(station)")
    }
    
    //load saved data as an array
    func loadArray() {
        
        vM = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "vReadings \(direction)\(station)") as? [String] ?? [String](repeating: "", count: 12)
        hM = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "hReadings \(direction)\(station)") as? [String] ?? [String](repeating: "", count: 12)
        
        print(vM)
        print(hM)
    }
      
}



struct Doors_test_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Doors_test(direction: "Direction")
    }
}
```

Comment: Rather than trying to use `UserDefaults` manually like this, you may want to look into the `@AppStorage` property wrapper.

Comment: @AppStorage var vM:[String]

Answer (score 0):

Big thanks for suggesting to use @AppStorage. After some research my code works.

```
import SwiftUI

struct Doors: View {
    
    //  var goingBack : Bool = viewWillDisappear(true)
    
    let fileName = Date.now
    
    let station : String
    let direction : String
    
    @AppStorage var vM: [String]
    @AppStorage var hM: [String]
    
    
    init(station: String, direction: String) {
        self.station = station
        self.direction = direction
        
//initialize dynamic keys for AppStorage
        self._vM = AppStorage(wrappedValue:[String](repeating: "", count: 12) , "Vert \(direction) \(station)")
        self._hM = AppStorage(wrappedValue:[String](repeating: "", count: 12), "Horiz \(direction) \(station)")
    
    }
        
    
    @FocusState private var amountIsFocust: Bool
    
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Form {
            ForEach(0..<12) { door in
                Section {
                    HStack {
                        Text ("Vert:")
                        
                        TextEditor(text: $vM[door])
                            .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
                            .focused($amountIsFocust)
                        
                    }
                    HStack {
                        Text ("Horizontal:")
                        TextEditor(text: $hM[door])
                            .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
                            .focused($amountIsFocust)
                        
                    }
                    
                } header: {
                    Text ("Door # \(door+1)")
                }
                
            }
            
        }
        .onAppear{
           loadArray()
           
        }
        .navigationTitle("Enter measurements")
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        .toolbar{
            ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .keyboard) {
                
                Spacer() //moves Done button to the right of the screen
                
                Button("Done") {
                    amountIsFocust = false
                    print(amountIsFocust)
                }
            }
        }
        .onDisappear {
            saveArray()
           
        }
        
        
    }
    
    func saveArray() {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(vM, forKey: "Vert \(direction) \(station)")
        UserDefaults.standard.set(hM, forKey: "Horiz \(direction) \(station)")
    }
    
    func loadArray() {
        
        vM = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "Vert \(direction) \(station)") as? [String] ?? [String](repeating: "", count: 12)
        hM = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "Horiz \(direction) \(station)") as? [String] ?? [String](repeating: "", count: 12)
        
        print(vM)
        print(hM)
    }

}



struct Doors_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Doors(station: "Station", direction: "Direction")
    }
}
```